# get all wordpress widgets within sidebar one and output each widget's info

Tags: json, wordpress, widget

I have x number of wordpress widgets in  sidebar one. how can I loop through each widget's info in  sidebar one?

Comment: I don't understand this question. Can you explain more, tell us what you've tried, and what you're trying to achieve please?

Comment: I put multiple widgets (different widgets) in sidebar 1. how can I get a count of widgets in sidebar1?